# SQL Else If statement to return text value from numeric value of another column - not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to have a calculated column `Site_Condition` that will return a text value based on the numeric value of another column `Condition_Score` which is in the same table.

Below is what I have tried inserting into the Computed Column Specification, I but get this message:

> Error validating the formula

I have also tried creating it from script "Create table as" using same syntax below  ie: Site_Condition AS (IF....)

What am I doing wrong?

```
IF([Condition_Score]<0.51,'Very poor',(ELSE  
IF([Condition_Score]<1.51,'Poor', ELSE 
IF([Condition_Score]<2.51,'Moderate',ELSE 
IF([Condition_Score]<3.51,'Good',ELSE 
IF([Condition_Score]>3.51,'Excellent'))))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, we use [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) rather than `IF`

```
CASE WHEN [Condition_Score]<0.51 THEN 'Very poor'
     WHEN [Condition_Score]<1.51 THEN 'Poor'
     WHEN [Condition_Score]<2.51 THEN 'Moderate'
     WHEN [Condition_Score]<3.51 THEN 'Good' 
     ELSE 'Excellent' END
```

But for completeness, here's the [`IIF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) version (note the extra "`I`", short for "Immediate If"):

```
IIF([Condition_Score]<0.51, 'Very poor',
    IIF([Condition_Score]<1.51, 'Poor',
    IIF([Condition_Score]<2.51, 'Moderate',
    IIF([Condition_Score]<3.51,'Good',
        'Excellent'))))
```

If I recall correctly, `IIF()` is not available until Sql Server 2016.

These also fix a bug whereby if the score was *exactly* 3.51 the result would be `NULL`.

Comment: . . Is that where the extra `I` comes from?  I learned something.

Answer (score -1):

**This is Simple way to ...perform your Query...**

```
DECLARE @Condition_Score AS DECIMAL
SET @Condition_Score=1.25

DECLARE @Message AS VARCHAR(50)


IF(@Condition_Score<0.51)
BEGIN
    SET @Message ='Very poor'
END

else IF(@Condition_Score<1.51)
BEGIN
    SET @Message ='poor'
END

ELSE IF(@Condition_Score<2.51)
BEGIN
    SET @Message ='Moderate'
END

ELSE IF (@Condition_Score<3.51)
BEGIN
    SET @Message ='Good'
END

ELSE IF(@Condition_Score>3.51)
BEGIN
    SET @Message='Excellent'
END

PRINT @Message
```

**Note:-Here " PRINT @Message" for Checking the Current Output**

Comment: You can't put this in a computed column